# Print nxn grid clockwise and print the sum of the diagonal elements

Tags: python

Example if n = 5 it should print

```
   21  22  23  24  25
   20  7   8   9   10
   19  6   1   2   11
   18  5   4   3   12
   17  16  15  14  13
```

Sum = 21+7+1+3+13+17+5+9+25
= 101

Here is my code

```
dim=5
result= n = 1
for in range(2,dim,2):
 for i in range(4):
    n+=k
    result+=n
print(result)
```

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute The Sum this way

```
def Spiral(size: int):
    if(size<=1):
        return 1
    else:
        Sum = 4*(size)**2 - 6(size-1)
        return (Sum+Spiral(size-2))

Spiral(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I made

```py
def spiral(n):

    # Initialize the values
    m = [[0]*n for _ in" "*n] # Define a list of list of n dim
    d = n
    v = n*n # values
    y = 0 # cord of y
    x = n # cord of x                                   
    
    
    while d > 0:                
        for _ in" "*d: # Equivalent to <=> for i in range(d)
            x -= 1 
            m[y][x] = v
            v-=1
        d -= 1

        for _ in" "*d:
            y += 1
            m[y][x] = v
            v-=1

        for _ in" "*d:
            x += 1
            m[y][x] = v
            v-=1
        d -= 1

        for _ in" "*d:
            y -= 1
            m[y][x] = v
            v-=1

    return m # return the list of list                              


n = 5

matrix = spiral(n)

# Print lines of the matrix
print("Matrix:")
for e in matrix:
    print(*e)

# Print the sum
print(f"Sum: {sum(matrix[i][i]for i in range(n)) + sum(matrix[i][n - i - 1]for i in range(n)) - 1}") # There is a - 1 at the end, because the value of the middle is 1
```

You can rewrite the while loop like this:

```py
while d > 0:
        for i in range(4):
            for _ in" "*d:
                if i%2:
                    y -= 2 * (i==3) - 1
                else:
                    x -= 2 * (i==0) - 1
                m[y][x] = v
                v-=1
            if i%2 == 0:
                d -= 1
```

It's shorter but less easy to understand

Comment: Thanks but I am not used to your syntax for the "for" loop but thanks

Comment: @SteveDaniel So why do you even use it in your code ?
And for i in" "*d # Equivalent to <=> for i in range(d)